# Template object gets "does not name a type."

Tags: templates, struct

I want to create a class that contains a struct with a template.  But it gives this error, and though I've seen other similar questions, I don't understand how or if I can declare this in a way that does not give this error.  thanks for your help.

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyTmpl {
public:
    MyTmpl() {}
    T body;
};

struct s1_t {
    std::string s;
    int x;
};

MyTmpl<s1_t> myc();
myc.body.s = "s1";
myc.body.x = 7;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //std::cout << myc.body.s << ':' << myc.body.x << std::endl;
}
```

This gives:

```
x.cpp:24:1: error: 'myc' does not name a type
    myc.body.s = "s1";
    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myc.body.s = "s1";
myc.body.x = 7;
```

Your *immediate* error is because you have this code where no code should be (at file level, outside of any function). You need to move it into `main` (or somewhere else that is is allowed to be, but probably `main` in this case).

The reason you see the `does not name a type` is simply because code *is* unexpected at that point so the compiler thinks you're trying to declare something (like, for example, `int x;`).

You'll get the same error with the code snippet:

```
//using nontype = int;
nontype x;
```

because `nontype` is not actually a type. If you however uncomment the `using` (a slightly more modern `typedef`), the `nontype` *becomes* a type and the error disappears.

---

Your second problem is that `MyTmpl<s1_t> myc();` is a function declaration, something that would become evident if you included in your `main`:

```
auto x = myc();
```

The linker would then complain about the lack of a `myc` function definition. You should change it to:

```
MyTmpl<s1_t> myc; // without the ().
```

---

Your third problem is that, while you're using the C++ language, you're not quite yet using the C++ *mindset.*  The whole *point* of classes is to encapsulate behaviour and state, something that's rather nullified if everything in your class is public :-)

Eventually (with experience), you'll get into the habit of privatising as much as possible, providing constructors, getters, setters, and so forth. Not an *immediate* issue for you but certainly something you'll want to work toward.

---

With those changes (other the the "C++ification") and uncommenting your output statement, the following resulting code compiles and runs fine, producing `s1:7` as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> class MyTmpl {
    public:

    MyTmpl() { }
    T body;
};

struct s1_t {
    std::string s;
    int x;
};

MyTmpl<s1_t> myc;  // variable, rather than function.
// code not allowed here.

int main() {
    myc.body.s = "s1";  // code allowed here.
    myc.body.x = 7;
    std::cout << myc.body.s << ':' << myc.body.x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I simplified this down to bare bones to make it easy to read, neither of these issues appears to be the problem.  The constructor is declared with no parameters and the myc is declared at global scope which is legal if not stylish.
I suspect what I'm trying to do is not legal, but I don't know why.

Comment: @eorojas, I made those changes based on the errors from `gcc` and they fix both the immediate issue and the function declaration issue (I've updated the answer with the final corrected code). Yes, you are allowed to declare `myc` where it is but the two lines following it (the assignments) are *not* valid. Re your simplification comment, if your code is different to what you posted, and the changes don't work on that different code, you need to post the *actual* code. Paraphrasing the Simpsons: Sorry. This answer only covers the actual problem, not made-up stuff. :-)

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still confused.  I was trying to hack get a simplified version to work and coded this way.  I don't know why it doesn't name a type.

Comment: @eorojas: it doesn't name a type because the compiler does not expect to see executable code at that point, so it thinks you're trying to declare something. I'll expand the answer to hopefully clarify ...